# when writing an email, can we write "Refer to your queries, please find the details below..."

Tags: email

"Refer to your queries, please find the details below..." Can we start the email saying "Refer to your queries.." or "Refer to the payment terms, your payment is due" ?

If not, what is the correct way to use "refer" in an email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Refer* there would be a command. You could say *please refer to our previous answers*; but I think you are wanting to talk about the reply referring, not the reader.

So you want *Referring to your queries*, or *In reference to your queries*. (the last would be my preferred option).

When it is the payment terms, you could say *Please refer to the payment terms*, putting the onus on the reader; or you could say something like *Based on the payment terms*, or *According to the payment terms*.

Comment: Thank you so much Colin! That will be very helpful!